# Is there any method to map multiple attributes in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an output from yum list module. The thing is I want to display the output without those number (epoch attribute). The problem is I couldn't find any solutions of mapping 2 attributes (name and version). All the solutions I found are connected to only 1 attribute ( envra) in my case.

```
  - name: check packages
    become: true
    yum:
      list: installed
    register: output

  - name: add lines to files
    lineinfile:
      dest: "./file.txt"
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ output.results | map(attribute='envra') |list }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

This is the output without any mapping. As you can see there are multiple attributes. I would like to display only name and version of the package.

```
10.112.65.15 {u'envra': u'0:GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el7.x86_64', u'name': u'GeoIP', u'repo': u'installed', u'epoch': u'0', u'version': u'1.5.0', u'release': u'14.el7', u'yumstate': u'installed', u'arch': u'x86_64'}
```

The closest to expected values is envra attribute, but still has those epoch number inside...

```
10.112.65.15 0:GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el7.x86_64
```

As I mentioned at the begging I would like to get output of something like that

```
10.112.65.15 GeoIP 1.5.0
```

or at least without epoch attribute.

I've also change approach and tried this method

```
  - name: add lines to files
    lineinfile:
      dest: "./file.txt"
      line: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }} "
    with_items:
      - "{{ output | json_query(my_query) | list }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    vars:
      my_query: "results[].[name, version]"
```

but received result was with '[]' and u' which I'd like to delete but don't exactly know how.

```
10.112.65.15 [u'GeoIP', u'1.5.0']
```

Comment: can you paste the other envra values, just wanted to check if I can use regex

Comment: Zeitounator resolution works, but if you want share your regexp here, this are the other values of envra
```10.112.65.15 {u'envra': u'0:GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el7.x86_64', u'name': u'GeoIP', u'repo': u'installed', u'epoch': u'0', u'version': u'1.5.0', u'release': u'14.el7', u'yumstate': u'installed', u'arch': u'x86_64'}
10.112.65.31 {u'envra': u'0:GConf2-3.2.6-8.el7.x86_64', u'name': u'GConf2', u'repo': u'installed', u'epoch': u'0', u'version': u'3.2.6', u'release': u'8.el7', u'yumstate': u'installed', u'arch': u'x86_64'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you extract the attribute or use json query ? Simply use the hash and print out the needed fields. The following should work out of the box.

```
- name: add lines to files
  lineinfile:
    dest: "./file.txt"
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item.name }} {{ item.version }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ output.results }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```